# Getting unexpected output when I changed struct value of variable - C

Tags: c, pointers, struct

When I change two values of the struct variable, I am getting unexpected output. But if I change these variables one by one, I don't get unexpected output. Why did this happen? Here are the codes and outputs.

[Unexpected Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DJYHB.png)

```
void check_tag_names(struct tag t){
struct tag *tagPtr;
tagPtr = &t;
   
strncpy(tagPtr->name,"name",4);
//strncpy(tagPtr->surname,"surname",7);
printf("%s",t.name); }
```

Output:namesurname

I don't understand why t.name is "namesurname" instead of just "name"

Comment: Post the code and both outputs in the question as text.

Comment: Hint: fix all warnings.

Comment: I added code. Warning is not about that problem.

Comment: As @dbush states it, fix the warnings. I guess your `tag` member `name` is a `char[4]`. And you should see that's not ok. Use `strncpy` instead of `strcpy`, it should help to understand why.

Comment: Please provide a [mre]. We need to see how you are calling the function.

Comment: Warning is fixed. strncpy() is used instead of strcpy() . But still output is "namesurname".

Comment: @Zilog80 yes name is a char[4] but i don't understand why that's not ok. Can you explain me ?

Comment: @volkanulker: In order to store the string `"name"`, you need a character array of at least size 5, as you also need room for the terminating null character. If there is not enough room, then `strcpy` will cause a [buffer overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow).

Comment: @AndreasWenzel It seems you are confusing me and the OP.

Comment: @Zilog80 Andreas Wenzel  thank you for help. I fixed that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`printf("%s",t.name);` expects `t.name` to refer to a *string*.

`t.name` is not a *string* as it lacks a *null character*`.

The result is *undefined behavior*.